# Mock/Stub super constructor invocation in Java for unit testing

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I want to unit-test my class with `JUnit` and `EasyMock`. It extends `android.location.Location`. But I am always getting `Stub!` exception because most of Android methods are not available in JVM runtime.

```
public class MyLocation extends Location {
    public MyLocation(Location l) {
        super(l);
    }

    public boolean methodUnderTest() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've tried to mock constructor invocation using `Powermock`, but it looks like it does not work for `super` calls. My test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Location.class)
public class MyLocationTest {
    @Test
    public void methodUnderTestReturnsTrue() throws Exception {
        Location locationMock = EasyMock.createMock(Location.class);
        expectNew(Location.class, Location.class).andReturn(locationMock);
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(locationMock);
        assertTrue(myLocation.methodUnderTest());
    }
}
```

An exception I am getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.location.Location.<init>(Location.java:6)
```

Obviously the solution is to execute this test in Android runtime (i.e. start Android Simulator). But I don't like this approach because it takes quite a few time to start such test suite. Is there a way to stub `super` invocation or probably there's better approach in testing such implementations?

Comment: [Mock a superclass constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421357/mock-a-superclass-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Taken straight from the Powermocks documentation.](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior)

Testing can then be done without invoking the `EvilParent` constructor.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExampleWithEvilParent.class)
public class ExampleWithEvilParentTest {

        @Test
        public void testSuppressConstructorOfEvilParent() throws Exception {
                suppress(constructor(EvilParent.class));
                final String message = "myMessage";
                ExampleWithEvilParent tested = new ExampleWithEvilParent(message);
                assertEquals(message, tested.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I somehow overlooked this method (tried it previously, but considered non-working as well).