# Unit Testing a static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, static, mockito

I am trying to write a test case for the method decrypt here.

```
    private static Codec codec;

    static {
        try {
            codec = new Codec(encryptionType, encryptionKey, false, true, false);
        } catch (CodecException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Codec initialisation failed", e);
        }
    }


    public static String decrypt(final String toDecrypt) throws CodecException {
        String decrypted = codec.decryptFromBase64(toDecrypt);
        if (decrypted.endsWith(":")) {
            decrypted = decrypted.substring(0, decrypted.length() - 1);
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
```

Test Case:

```
    @Mock
    private Codec codec;
    @Test
    public void test_decrypt_Success() throws CodecException {
        when(codec.decryptFromBase64(TestConstants.toDecrypt)).thenReturn(TestConstants.decrypted);
        assertEquals(DocumentUtils.decrypt(TestConstants.toDecrypt), TestConstants.decrypted);
    }
```

Since this is a static method, I can't inject an instance of the class in the test suite and mock its codec. The above code throws an error from the codec library at assert as expected.

What is your approach to testing static methods like this? Or should I not be writing tests for this at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock/Stub super constructor invocation in Java for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255332/mock-stub-super-constructor-invocation-in-java-for-unit-testing)

Comment: Use PowerMock to mock static methods. But you are not even calling the decrypt(final String toDecrypt) method in your Junit. Without that, the statement when(codec.decryptFromBase64(TestConstants.toDecrypt)).thenReturn(TestConstants.decrypted); has no meaning.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo my bad. Updated the q. I meant to call decrpyt in assert.

Comment: @talex, I am not trying to mock a constructor or a super constructor. I want to mock a static variable initialised in static block in a static method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, static methods are not designed to set dependencies.
So switching the dependency into a mock is really not natural.
You could provide a `static` setter for the field such as :

```
private static Codec codec;
public static void setCodec(Codec codec){
   this.codec = codec;
}
```

And  you could set a mock with `setCodec(...)` but ugh...

But forget, just do things well : refactor the code to remove all static and introduce a constructor that sets the codec.

```
private Codec codec;
public MyClassUnderTest(Codec codec){
   this.codec codec;
}
```

IOC could help here to make the class under test a singleton and ease the  dependency injections.
If not possible in your case, Java 5 enumeration could help you for at least the singleton concern.

Comment: I was not using the static eariler. But a peer pointed out that this is a util class and as such I should be initialising the codec only once. How do we write mocks for util static classes?

Comment: @tanvi I suspected the same! You have some choices like writing proper object oriented code and move this code into a separate class which does this specific job and non-statically...... or write the static setter and adapt the code accordingly...or use PowerMockito to mock static methods:) Refer https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/11/testing-and-mocking-of-static-methods-in-java/ for PowerMockito example.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo how would you suggest I adapt the code according to the static setter?

Comment: I agree with a single initialization but I don't about static usage. Ok in Java static methods are easy to write and simplify client usage for util methods. But it also hs some limitations : this hardcodes dependencies and so make it no naturally switchable. I generally write static methods only for methods that never need to mock any things. About your question, the setter is a way. PowerMock is another one. But I would avoid both in your case as you are the api/component developer.

Comment: @tanvi, like David has suggested.

Comment: @davidxxx, yes, I would rather suggest separating this code out into a singleton class since it has a codec dependency. This shall make it easier to test it/mock it.

Comment: @tanvi, create a separate singleton class (follow SOLID principles) and use it for this functionality. I think that will serve the purpose and also help you test it more easily.

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo I do not want to make my class under test a singleton as it is a utils final class. I do not own the Codec class.

Comment: @Ankur Chrungoo I agree completely. This makes things clean.

Comment: @tanvi The fact that the dependency is not in your base code will never prevent you from defining a singleton that uses that.

Comment: @davidxxx This is a final utils class for which I do not want to create a singleton. All the methods in the class are static.

Comment: @tanvi, if you do not want to modify, then you should use the other options that david and me mentioned. (static setter/ PowerMockito). These are kind of hacks which are needed for mocking and testing static methods/classes.

Comment: If you don't want to change your mind, stay on my initial comment : powermock or the static setter.

Comment: Thanks @davidxxx. I will go with a setter and mock the getter.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different and shortcut ways of achieving the same (as pointed out in comments and other answers), but not all of them are good in the long run especially.

I would suggest creating a Singleton class which implements the Decrypt functionality. So, you won't have to create multiple instances, and don't really need to have static method for decrypting as well, and you can inject your codec once and more easily (I assume you don't have multiple types of codec as per your comments. But, if you do, then the functionality shall be adapted accordingly).

For more reference: [Why use a singleton instead of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765060/why-use-a-singleton-instead-of-static-methods)

For reference on why static should be used carefully:-
[Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil?rq=1)

Comment: Agree concerning the main idea but in Java I prefer IOC to old singleton way with the static `getInstance()` method.

Comment: @davidxxx, yes, but many times that doesn't suit us, although that is the most ideal way in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience in those cases I just prepare all instances in a @Before method:

```
private Codec codec;

@Before
public void setup() throws CodecException {
  codec = new Codec(encryptionType, encryptionKey, false, true, false);
}
```